# Signature from "TNE <tne@garudalinux.org>" is unknown trust - Invalid or Corrupted package

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, upgrade, pacman, packaging

While running `pacman -Syu`

After "(8/8) checking package integrity"
I'm facing the following issue with these packages:

```
error: 7-zip: signature from "TNE <tne@garudalinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/7-zip-23.01-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: brave-bin: signature from "TNE <tne@garudalinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/brave-bin-1:1.52.126-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: pamac-aur: signature from "TNE <tne@garudalinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/pamac-aur-11.0.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: spotify: signature from "TNE <tne@garudalinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/spotify-1:1.2.13.661-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: visual-studio-code-bin: signature from "TNE <tne@garudalinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/visual-studio-code-bin-1.79.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: yay: signature from "TNE <tne@garudalinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/yay-12.1.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: zoom: signature from "TNE <tne@garudalinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/zoom-5.15.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

So far, I've tried running this (without success):

- `sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring` | `pacman -Su`
- `pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring` | `pacman-key --refresh-keys`
- `pacman-key --delete 91BD8815FE0040FA7FF5D68754C28F4FF5A1A949`  | `pacman-key --populate archlinux`
- `pacman-key --delete D6C9442437365605`  | `pacman-key --populate archlinux`
- `sudo pacman -Sc`
- `sudo pacman -Fy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got some help on Linux.Chat Discord server, and Theros (the user that help me) found a way to solve this issue:

"looks like your after 0xd6c9442437365605
thats from ubuntus keyserver
https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=tne%40garudalinux.org&fingerprint=on&op=index
though considering that garuda uses chaotic
you should only really need the chaotic-keychain
and yeh, that seems about right, considering it looks like archcraft are using chaotic for stuff
https://github.com/archcraft-os/archcraft/issues/251 "

So I've manage to fix it by following this steps:

- `sudo pacman-key --recv-key D6C9442437365605 --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com`
- `sudo pacman-key --lsign-key D6C9442437365605`
- `sudo pacman -U 'https://cdn-mirror.chaotic.cx/chaotic-aur/chaotic-keyring.pkg.tar.zst' 'https://cdn-mirror.chaotic.cx/chaotic-aur/chaotic-mirrorlist.pkg.tar.zst'`